# why I can't swap unicode characters in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, unicode-string, python-unicode

Why I can't swap unicode characters in code?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

character_swap = {'ą': 'a', 'ż': 'z', 'ó': 'o'}

text = 'idzie wąż wąską dróżką'

print text

print ''.join(character_swap.get(ch, ch) for ch in text)
```

OUTPUT: idzie wąż wąską dróżką

EXPECTED OUTPUT: idzie waz waska drozka

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: as you can see in code swap one character for another change ą to a, ż to z and ó to o (polish language specific letters)

Comment: @Gunnm provide the expected output

Comment: Are you getting any errors or such?

Comment: None at all. It just ignores what is in character swap but if you will add normal letter like fe swap d for D or i for q it works. It has only problems with polish letters for some reason it just skips them.

You can copy and paste this code. I'm using PyCharm to work with python

Comment: Your key value is not being stored as a unicode string. print `character_swap` and you will get `{'\xc3\xb3': 'o', '\xc5\xbc': 'z', '\xc4\x85': 'a'}` as output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode you text first then decode the characters again :

```
>>> print ''.join(character_swap.get(ch.encode('utf8'), ch) for ch in text.decode('utf8'))
idzie waz waska drozka
```

Its because of that python list comprehension doesn't encode your unicode by default,actually what you are doing her is  :

```
>>> [i for i in text]
['i', 'd', 'z', 'i', 'e', ' ', 'w', '\xc4', '\x85', '\xc5', '\xbc', ' ', 'w', '\xc4', '\x85', 's', 'k', '\xc4', '\x85', ' ', 'd', 'r', '\xc3', '\xb3', '\xc5', '\xbc', 'k', '\xc4', '\x85']
```

And for a character like `ą` we have :

```
>>> 'ą'
'\xc4\x85'
```

As you can see within a list comprehension python split it in 2 part `\xc4` and `\x85`. so for getting ride of that you can first decode your text by `utf8` encocding :

```
>>> [i for i in text.decode('utf8')]
[u'i', u'd', u'z', u'i', u'e', u' ', u'w', u'\u0105', u'\u017c', u' ', u'w', u'\u0105', u's', u'k', u'\u0105', u' ', u'd', u'r', u'\xf3', u'\u017c', u'k', u'\u0105']
```

Comment: It works. Thank you very much for help how exactly decode and encode command work?

Comment: @Gunnm Welcome. let me explain! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your string should be stored as a unicode string.

Change these two lines and it should work:

```
character_swap = {u'ą': 'a', u'ż': 'z', u'ó': 'o'}

text = u'idzie wąż wąską dróżką'
```